# Custom password match validator is not working in angular5

Tags: angular, validation, angular5, angular2-forms, customvalidator

I am implementing custom validator to match password in my component.

Here is my component.ts form declaration

```
this.addUserForm = new FormGroup({
  firstname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  lastname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  city: new FormControl(),
  address: new FormControl(),
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
  confirm_password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, ConfirmPasswordValidator.MatchPassword]),
  role: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  phone: new FormControl(),
  companyCode: new FormControl(this.local_storage.getCurrentUser().companyCode, [Validators.required])
});
```

here is my custom.validator.ts

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class ConfirmPasswordValidator {
static MatchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
    let password = control.get('password').value;
    let confirmPassword = control.get('confirm_password').value;

    if (password != confirmPassword) {
        console.log('false')
        control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({ ConfirmPassword: true });
    } else {
        return null
    }
  }
 }
```

Here is my component.html input part

```
 <label class="col-form-label">Password</label>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="addUserForm.get('password').touched && addUserForm.get('password').invalid && addUserForm.get('password').errors.required">
              Password is required
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="addUserForm.get('password').touched && addUserForm.get('password').invalid && addUserForm.get('password').errors.minlength && !addUserForm.get('password').errors.required">
              Password length must be greater than 6
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="addUserForm.get('confirm_password').touched && addUserForm.get('confirm_password').invalid && addUserForm.get('confirm_password').errors.ConfirmPassword">
              Password deesn't match
          </div>
```

But it is giving this error 
 `property 'value' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at ConfirmPasswordValidator.MatchPassword (user.validator.ts:5)`

Project structure and directory is very complex and huge that's why can't share all component and html code. 
What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Form Group Validator**

Update `MatchPassword` to work on form group level so you don't need to add a custome validator to `confirmPassword` control

```
static MatchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
    let password = control.get('password').value;
    let confirmPassword = control.get('confirm_password').value;

    if (password != confirmPassword) {
      return { ConfirmPassword: true };
    } else {
        return null
    }
  }
```

and add this validator for formGroup validators options

```
{ validators: ConfirmPasswordValidator.MatchPassword }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ct5jtd)

**Form Control Validator**

if you want to add the validation to the control so the control parameter will be confirm password control and you need to use parent to access to the form group and get the value of password control

```
this.form = fb.group({
  password: [null, [Validators.required]],
  confirm_password: [null, [Validators.required, MatchPassword]]
})
```

MatchPassword validator

```
function MatchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
  let parent = control.parent
  if (parent) {
    let password = parent.get('password').value;
    let confirmPassword = control.value;

    if (password != confirmPassword) {
      return { ConfirmPassword: true };
    } else {
      return null
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-myw6pu)

Comment: The second solution is a bad one, because the validator will only be called when you change the confirm password value, and not when modifying the password value.

Comment: Thanx. your example worked form me. I modified your example according to my need.

Comment: Now I see the error the validator will work on control change so if I have change password the confirm is still valid  in order the form control validator to work probably we need to run updateValueAndValidity for `confirm_password` every time the password value change  @JBNizet

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

First: You're getting a child from control named 'password' and another child form control named 'confirmPassword' from the control passed to the validator. So what the validator is supposed to validate is a `FormGroup`, containing these two form controls. But you're not setting this validator on the form group. You're setting it on the form control `confirmPassword`. You need to set this validator on the enclosing form group.

Second: a validator is not supposed to modify the control it is validating. Its sole responsibility is to **return** the error(s) (or null if there is no error). Angular will set the validity of the control based on what you return. So its code should be

```
static MatchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
  const password = control.get('password').value;
  const confirmPassword = control.get('confirm_password').value;

  if (password != confirmPassword) {
    return { ConfirmPassword: true };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Or, written more concisely:

```
static MatchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
  return control.get('password').value != control.get('confirm_password').value ? { ConfirmPassword: true } : null;
}
```

Comment: i didn't find on google that how can i place validator inside FormGroup. Can you tell me how to specify validator on FormGroup?

Comment: Read the api documentation, and/or the official guide about form validation: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup, https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-reactive-forms-1

Comment: i updated my post according to your guidelines but still same error. Please see my updated post i updated the code

Comment: The validator is still set on the ConfirmPassword field. I've rollbacked your changes in the question, because my answer doesn't make sense if you half-fix the code in the question.

Comment: i updated my code. Now erorr is not occuring and in console it is priting false also but in templeate warning is not showing. Is my condition wrong in *ngIF?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. The validator is on the form group, so what it makes valid or invalid is the form group, not the ConfirmPassword form control. This is explained in the guide I linked to. Why don't you read the documentation. And please, stop editing the question, since it makes the answers look incorrect, since they talk about code that is fixed.

Comment: I tried different *ngIf conditions from documentation. But none of that is working. Can you tell me what correct condtion will be to access that error occuring?

Comment: `<div *ngIf="addUserForm.invalid">The form group is invalid</div>`.

Comment: `<div *ngIf="addUserForm.hasError('ConfirmPassword')">  Password doesn't match
</div> `@FahadHassanSubzwari

Comment: you have explain the validator job very well  @JBNizet